# How to send curl PUT request in android

Tags: android, curl, request, put

How to send this curl request in android.

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 9a18aae3-1269-485f-8408-cba7289fca15" -X PUT "https://graph-na04-useast2.api.smartthings.com/api/smartapps/installations/f9ec2874-3033-4fed-a578-c642f54b015f/switches/on"

Comment: Sending-and-Managing-Network-Requests
http://guides.codepath.com/android/Sending-and-Managing-Network-Requests

Comment: What HTTP client API are you using? `HttpUrlConnection`? OkHttp? Apache's library? Something else?

Comment: This http request changing Fan status.....(IOT)

Comment: Please suggest one among three library with an example it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Please see CodePaths wonderful guide on [Sending-and-Managing-Network-Requests](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Sending-and-Managing-Network-Requests#sending-an-http-request-third-party)

They introduce you to Sending an HTTP Request (Third Party) or Sending an HTTP Request (The "Hard" Way). With this guide you should be good to go...

> Sending an HTTP Request (Third Party)
>
> There are at least three major third-party networking libraries you
>   should consider using.
>
> See the Android Async Http Client guide for making basic network
>   calls. It is the library often used for learning Android but would not
>   be used in a production application.
>
> See the OkHttp guide for making synchronous and asynchronous calls.
>
> See also the Retrofit guide, which uses OkHttp and makes it easier to
>   make more RESTful API calls. Read through this guide to understand how
>   the Gson library works with Retrofit. Check out the Volley guide, a
>   library built by Google that has fallen out of favor for OkHttp. It
>   was one of the first networking libraries released for Android and
>   provides a more convenient way to make networking requests than using
>   AsyncTask.